# Why does a query on text column in postgres work having `_` works. But without `_` does not work

Tags: postgresql, sql-like

This is basically a ends with query on text column in postgres 13.1

```
SELECT translations.value 
FROM "translations" 
WHERE (VALUE ILIKE '%deg!');
```

```
 value
-------
(0 rows)
```

Whereas

```
SELECT "translations".* 
FROM "translations" 
WHERE (VALUE ILIKE '%deg!_');
```

```
                    value
---------------------------------------------
 --- Gratulerer, du har <br> registrert deg!+
 --- Gratulerer, du har <br> registrert deg!+
 --- Vi gleder oss til å trene med deg!     +
 --- Vi gleder oss til å trene med deg!     +
 --- Vi kommer snart tilbake til deg!       +
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because there is an additional character after the exclamation mark.

To find out what character that might be, convert the results to `bytea`, so that you can see them byte for byte:

```
SELECT CAST (translations.value AS bytea)
FROM translations
WHERE (VALUE ILIKE '%deg!_');
```

Comment: Does postgres add something at the end while saving on text column ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. That must come from your client code.